# Dart fix by issue type

Tags: flutter, dart

the following command , applies all changes in bulk

```
dart fix --apply
```

How can I tell `dart fix` only fix specific issue? i.e only fix all `Prefer const with constant constructors.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: (august 2023)

```
dart fix --apply --code=prefer_const_constructors
```

To fix specific issue. This information is hard to find, just with trial and error to get it.